# Style inside div tag

Tags: html

I try to modify the style of div tag using this:

```
<div style="background-color: #ffff0g; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000; height: 500px">
```

However the height doesn't working. Is there anything I should fix in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check blow `html` with `inline css`

```html
<div style="background-color: #ffff00; border-width:1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000; height: 500px">
```